# Microsoft Graph Beta - Convert from EwsId to RestId or RestImmutableEntryId

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

I'm trying to convert an `EwsId` to either a `RestId` or `RestImmutableEntryId` using the beta version of Microsoft Graph.

It works fine to convert `RestId`s to `RestImmutableEntryId`s, but so far no luck converting from an `EwsId`. The documentation is understandably not abundant at this point since it's in beta but [I've found some documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id#updating-existing-data) that's saying it's supposed to be possible:

> **Note:** You can also use `translateExchangeIds` to migrate Exchange Web Services applications to Microsoft Graph".

What I've done is retrieving and `Id` from a `.msg` file, converted it to a Base64 string, and sent the conversion request:

```
var client = new GraphServiceClient(etc..);
var messageId = Convert.ToBase64String(
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("<someId@something.prod.outlook.com>")
);

var req = client
    .Me
    .TranslateExchangeIds(new [] { messageId },
        ExchangeIdFormat.RestImmutableEntryId,
        ExchangeIdFormat.EwsId);

var translateExchangeIdsCollectionPage = await req.Request().PostAsync();
```

I expect to get a `ConvertIdResult` back, but instead I'm getting a `Microsoft.Graph.GenericError`

> "[IdConverter::IsPublicFolder] Invalid compression id"`

I haven't been able to find any documentation related to this error, and what to do to fix it. I'm no expert on Outlook, so for all I know I'm using the wrong id or something.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urltokenencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `Convert.ToBase64String`.

While both technically generate a Base64 encoded string, there are some subtle differences in the encoding. This is because Base64 considers `+`, `/`,  and `=` characters as valid while URLs do not. To deal with this, [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648) defines a `base64url` encoding that uses only URL safe characters. Exchange uses this Base64Url encoding to encode IDs.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I should've said I'm on dotnet core. For others wondering, the equivalent to `UrlTokenEncode` seems to be [WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.webutilities.webencoders.base64urlencode?view=aspnetcore-2.2).  

I'm not sure this is the problem though. It's a POST request to the `Microsoft Graph` API to convert it, where the id is part of the request body. I did try it anyway, you never know. But got back a `FormatError` saying __Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.__

Comment: There may be differences between those two encodings. The reason you need to use the same encoding is that it is looking up the record by the _encoded id_. If you encode it differently than Exchange, it will fail to match.

Comment: There is a closed issue on Github on this topic as well: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/3554